# Does Facebook profile picture url become invalid when the access token expire?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I saw that it is not possible anymore to get the profile picture by simply passing the user ID.

You can however get an url to the profile picture by passing an access token with the public_profile permission.

What happen when the access token expire? Will the url to the profile picture also become invalid?

Can I simply store the url in my database without having to look it up every time with an access token?

Comment: When the access token expires, then any API call you pass the access token to, will of course also not work any more. The _result_ of that API call (URL to the image CDN, currently starting with `https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic/...`) however includes its own parameters to limit its validity, so that is not directly dependent on the access token; but those CDN URLs also expire after a certain time.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook URLs may change, so you can never be sure one URL stays the same. I would suggest storing the image, not the URL - but of course offer an option for users to delete his data later.